# C code for enabling theming in Windows

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, winapi, themes

I have a small code below that is suppose to enable/disable themes in Windows 7.
This is a Win32 console app that I compile with Visual Studio 2010.

When executing, it works well for disabling themes.
However, enabling does not work because the code hangs and does not exit.

I found that I can fix hanging by commenting the pragma option line.
The code exits correctly but the theme is still not enabled.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Uxtheme.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//#pragma comment(linker, "/entry:main")

// Main application function
int main(void) {

    if (!IsThemeActive()) 
        EnableTheming(TRUE);
    else
        EnableTheming(FALSE);

    printf("Last error: %d", GetLastError());

    SendNotifyMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, NULL, (LPARAM)TEXT("VisualEffects"));

}
```

Questions:

1. How to enable themes in general? I am missing something?
2. How to make it work with the pragma option that creates a custom entry point? I need a very small executable size.

Thank you very much

Comment: check the result of the api with GetLastError()

Comment: It says 1722 "The RPC server is unavailable". The Themes service is running and I am running the program under an elevated admin account. If I check manually the checkbox "Enable visual styles .." in Computer Properties, themes get enabled without any problem.

Comment: A littre precision to my previous comment. The return code is 1722 only when themes are disabled manually via the checkbox mentionned above. If themes are disabled by my code, enabling them returns 0 as error code but there is no changes on the screen.